# What does Islam say about adventure sports?

Tags: sharia, sports

Adventure sports like trekking, bungee jumping, surfing, skydiving, etc. are practiced by people just for the sake of enjoyment and passtime. People take this inspite of the risk of life. What does Islam say about risking life for games?

Comment: They are not explicitly forbidden and hence permissible.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of other religious views in this discussion.  Might be better to ask this question at the respective Exchange site or a discussion forum.

Comment: @Shahab You can argue a case for "threatening life for the sake of entertainment is unislamic."

Answer (score 7):

As other questions state, in Islam, everything wordly is permissible until proven haram. So the question is, is this haram or not?

I don't give fatwa :) I will however mention some points to keep in mind:

- Your body is not your own; it's a loaner, and you are expected to maintain it well (see Youssef G.'s answer)
- Islam allows and encourages entertainment, fun, and enjoying yourself -- but within permissible means.
- Excessive (obsessive) entertainment, like excessive anything, becomes haram.

As I mentioned in a comment, you can argue that "risking your neck for sheer entertainment is unislamic." However, I think practitioners of said sports will generally agree that the risk is very low -- no more than, say, getting into a car accident.

I will also say that Islam encourages physical fitness -- rasulullah said that every Muslim should know how to swim, ride a horse, etc. So your intention may play a big part in determining the permissibility of this.

Just some considerations to keep in mind. I'm sure you can ask a scholar and get a solid answer on your particular circumstance.

Comment: One of the mods removed my "I'm sure you can ask a scholar ..." to the end. I'm not aware of any scholars on the site! That's always an authoritative source to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Islam, your body is given to you.  You will be judged on how well you take care of it.  Ultimately, mothers and fathers will argue that putting yourself in undue danger is Haram, but nothing of the sort is explicitly stated in the Qu'arn or Hadith.

Comment: (Opinion) I think intentions, frequency, level of recklessness and the such will play a role in that judgement, but its purely conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I think that everything has risk . Crossing a road can lead to a car accident. I personally believe thay Allah decides your future and whatever he wants to happen to you. If he wants you to die in a certain way or on a certain date it will happen because of Allah's decision and not because what sport you do like bungee jumping. I think bungee jumping and sky diving have the same risk as everything else like car accidents etc. It's not like your jumping off the roof with no rope.

Comment: Don't express your own opinion or support them using authentic references from hadiths and noble Quran. Your answer in the present status is not acceptable.