# Are sports like boxing and martial arts permissible in Islam?

Tags: sports

In martial arts you often have to have sparring sessions or even inter-club championships where you have to hurt the opponent to win the fight. Similarly, in boxing you're hitting the opponent to gain points.

Are these kinds of sports permissible in Islam in which there are chances of hurting the opponent?

Comment: Related: [Islam and adventure sports.](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/204/islam-and-adventure-sports)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Boxing:**

The scholars (sunni) has unanimously agreed that boxing as practiced nowadays in contests and sport centers in our countries is a prohibited practice in the Islamic Shari`ah. It is based on permitting fighters to injure each other to the extent that could lead to blindness, permanent severe brain damage, serious fractures, or death; without imposing any liability on the other party. In addition, spectators derive pleasure from the winner's victory and feelings of happiness for the injury suffered by the loser. This is absolutely prohibited and rejected in Islam for Allah states (Exalted be He) :

> ...and do not throw yourselves into destruction **[Surah Al-Baqarah 2:195]**

And His Statement (Exalted be He):

> And do not kill yourselves (nor kill one another). Surely, Allâh is
>   Most Merciful to you. **[Surah Al-Nisa 4:29]**

In addition to the statement of the Prophet (peace be upon him):

> There should be neither causing nor reciprocating harm. **[Sunan Ibn Majah no. 2340]**

**Second: Freestyle Wrestling:**

As for freestyle wrestling in which wrestlers deem it lawful to hurt one another and cause injury, the council views that it completely resembles boxing even if there are slight differences between them, because the legal physical reasons for the prohibitions of boxing exist in freestyle wrestling that assumes the nature of fighting. Thus, it takes the same ruling of prohibition. **Regarding other types of wrestling practiced for physical exercise without causing any injury, they are legally permissible and the council does not view their prohibition.**

**The other opinion is** :

There is no harm in practicing freestyle wrestling so long as it does not involve danger, harm, or uncovering one's Awrah (parts of the body that must be covered in public). The Hadith mentions that:

> Prophet (peace be upon him) wrestled Yazid ibn Rukanah and defeated
>   him (peace be upon him). **[Sunan Abu Dawud no.4078]**

This is because the basic ruling expresses permission unless otherwise declared by Islamic law.

So as long as there is no harm to anyone involved or uncovering one's Awrah, it is permissible to **practice** this type of wrestling.

Moreover, it is permissible to practice arts of fighting for the cause of Jihad.

Allah says,

> And make ready against them all you can of power, including steeds of
>   war (tanks, planes, missiles, artillery) to threaten the enemy of
>   Allâh and your enemy **[Surah Al-Anfal, 8: 60]**

And there are martial arts which require bowing to the opponent and such an act of bowing is not permissible since bowing is a religious act of Ibadah (worship) and Ibadah should be devoted to Allah Alone.

**Source:** [The ruling on boxing, bullfighting, and freestyle wrestling](http://alifta.com/Fatawa/FatawaChapters.aspx?View=Page&PageID=421&PageNo=1&BookID=14)

[What are the categories of permissible games in Islam?](http://alifta.com/Fatawa/Fatwaprint.aspx?id=5629&BookID=7&sectionid=)

[Martial arts with bowing](http://www.alifta.com/Fatawa/FatawaSubjects.aspx?View=Page&NodeID=3432&PageID=113&SectionID=7&SubjectPageTitlesID=51159&MarkIndex=1&0)

Comment: YOU must understand just becuz boxing and wrestling is a sport that inflicts harm doesn't make it haram. Cuz our prophet and the Sahabas used to wrestle and wresting is a martial art and combat sport...which also includes inflicting haram. There are many other sports that inflict haram and are dangerous doesn't make them haram. Yes, an argument could be made where say, striking the face and obliterating the sanctity of the face is impermissible but other than that I don't think any other explanation would be valid.

Comment: Look, I get it. Combat sports are harsh and yes it is about inflicting harm and stuff, but that's essentially what the sport is about.  At the end of the day, the main idea is respect. You enter the ring respecting each other, allowing each other to demonstrate your combat skills on each other's body. And after the final bell, u leave the ring with respect and as brothers. This leads to my second point, about how some martial arts include bowing. Look, bowing is no way an act of worship or anything. It's simply an act of respect and trust that you give your opponent.

Answer (score -2):

Martial Arts is Allowed. Our prophet Muhammad sallalahu alaihiwasalam said that every Muslim needs to know Martial arts, Swimming and Horse Riding and is Sunnat.

Hope It helps

Comment: Kindly cite the source for the saying of the prophet ﷺ.