# Is boxing haram?

Tags: fiqh, sports

The other day, I had a discussion with a guy who seems to know a little about Islam and its related laws. I recommended that he box three days a week. He said that boxing was not allowed in Islam because it was dangerous and violent, where the players could get hurt badly. So is boxing really haram?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is playing sports like boxing and martial arts allowed in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/is-playing-sports-like-boxing-and-martial-arts-allowed-in-islam)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of points to look at when we talk about boxing.  One, is that it inflicts harm and allows people to hurt themselves just for fun/sport, and they can injure each other which could lead to brain damage and other things, while at the same time those that watch have fun watching them, sometimes they place bets and so on.  The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said:

> لَا ضَرَرَ وَلَا ضِرَارَ
>
> There should be neither harming nor reciprocating harm

[Al Arba'een Annawaweeyah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1400320)

( See more information about this in [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/is-playing-sports-like-boxing-and-martial-arts-allowed-in-islam) )

The other point to look at is, the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said:

> إِذَا ضَرَبَ أَحَدُكُمْ فَلْيَتَّقِ الْوَجْهَ
>
> When one of you inflicts a beating, he should avoid striking the face

[Sunnan Abi Dawood](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/143)

To hit the face of a person (or animal) is haram, as is clear in the above Hadith and many others like it, so when we look at boxing the face does get hit/punches do reach the face, and that is haram.

So in short conclusion, yes boxing is haram.

Comment: Boxing is not haraam. Hitting on the face yes. You still can do boxing by punching on the bag or pads.

Comment: yes, but I am not referring to that at all in my answer, for a bag is not a person, and the boxing practiced todays world is considered haram.  As for punching a bag or something then there is no problem, as far as I know.

Comment: @مجاهد I get ure points about punching the face and stuff...but just becuz boxing is a sport that inflicts harm doesn't make it haram. Cuz our prophet and the Sahabas used to wrestle and wresting is a martial art and combat sport...which also includes inflicting haram. I think you should review the true meaning and context of the hadith where our prophet says there should be neither harming nor reciprocating harm...maybe it has to do with doing physical and mental harm to the individual for the sake of doing harm rather than for the sake of sport.

Answer (score 0):

I've been training for well over 25 years in mostly martial arts but have trained in boxing, thai-boxing and full contact karate. Hitting the face whether for sport, fun or in aggression is haram. Islam teaches us to look after our body through good health and exercise, not to compete against our fellow brothers for status and arrogance which sadly is the state of boxing.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I have  read and researched, Boxing overall is not Haram but sparring and actual competitive fights are haram as it involves striking to the face which is made clear in the Quran to be haram.

Comment: Salam and welcome on islam SE. Please consider adding references to support your claims. I strongly recommend you to take the [tour], check our [help] and read [answer],

Comment: It is not haram neither to do wrestling?

Answer (score 0):

The boxing as we have it today has some aspects which go against the religion, such as hits to the face, and the risk of injury to self and to an opponent. It is not permissible to go into situations where harm is expected just for entertainment. Dr Zakir Naik explained this very well.[Here](https://youtu.be/a5snOQlCous)

Answer (score -1):

I believe actions associated with the sport are haram. Actions like people gambling and the consumption of alcohol. The boxer may not partake in such things. The sport itself can not be declared haram according to the Hadeeths quoted. Here is why.

The first hadith simply states that our beloved Prophet said: "There should be neither harming (darar) nor reciprocating harm (dirar). "

however whoever quoted this left out something that our Ummah fails at again and again...context. There should be neither harming nor reciprocating harm in what? I'm sure he is not talking about boxing...since the sport did not exist at that time.

The second hadith gives a context clue that it is about beating as a punishment. So that does not relate to boxing as a sport because trust me people who are in there fighting are not punishing each other by any definition of the word.

Honestly I think the fatwa on boxing and many of the people who say it is haram is because people do not want another influential person like Muhammad Ali to emerge again. Because of Allah's gift to him in that sport he was the biggest voice for Islam in America. Sometimes something that seems bad can do a lot of good.

Answer (score -1):

Look i have researched alot and still dont know if it is halal or not but i found this. Boxing is a sport which has both hand wraps to protect the hands and gloves to protect your opponent face, and both fighters are doing it participantly. There are ring side doctors and alot of safety procedures and check ups. If you are a person to say boxing is haram cause people died in it then this is not logical, people dont die from boxing but they die in boxing due to weight cuts and constant sparring, if a fighter controls their weight and minimises sparring their is so much less chance for them to be hurt in any way. In addition being a great boxer could help islam in many ways and share good things and belief converting millions and also making million and giving to charity (this was done by fighters like muhammed ali, prince nassem, khabib and others). Lets say if all these were haram including acting and everything how are muslims going to put their word, if no muslim celebrities. People look up to celebrities and time has changed back then celebrities wont like now where you must be in an art or sport industry to become big and get people to follow you. However that said boxing can be haram as their are hadiths from prophet SAW prevent hitting the face so i honestly dont the answer but these are things to consider.

Answer (score -2):

Folks you need to be a little realistic here. Boxing is NOT haraam. It is an art. A form of fitness. A form of self defence. A form of discipline.  If you want to guy by the letter of the law, YOU are not hitting someone in the face. No. There is a set of wraps and thick gloves in between your fist and the opponents face. 
Also bear in mind, this is a sport in which you have two equally willing participants. 
If we start calling this like this haraam, we would all need to emigrate to strictly religious countries as you could call living in western countries haraam too.

Guys, boxing is an excellent, tremendously rewarding sport which teaches respect and honour whilst getting you into fantastic shape. You meet many people from many cultures and thoroughly enjoy training together. Notwithstanding the fact that we are keeping youngsters off the streets and assisting them towards being more productive in their lives.

Let's be careful about what we label as haraam.

I run a boxing class at the mosque and not one person had felt the need to tell me it may be haraam!

Comment: Brother, Boxing in of it's self is not haram, but as it is practiced today it is haram.  It doesn't matter whether you are wearing thick gloves and not directly hitting on the fce, it is the fact that the punches do reach the face, and in boxing as it is practiced today, damage is done, and the research in the damage of "sports" like boxing and football are available on the net.  Furthermore the benefits of boxing is less then the far more damage and harm it can cause, if you want to benefit from boxing then just do all the exercises, punch a bag, but don't go into the ring.

Comment: Lastly, we cannot say something is haram without proof, and with boxing (as is practiced today), the proof of it's damage (look at Muhammad Ali if you wish) is known.

Comment: Muhammad Ali has parkinsons. How many non boxer's have parkinsins. It not a boxing disease.