# Exception to the ruling of striking the face

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, war, sports

Hitting the bare face of someone is considered to be haram based on the hadiths of the prophet (PBUH):

> “When any one of you fights, **let him avoid (striking) the face**.” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, al-Fath, 5/215).
>
> ‘**Stone her, but avoid the face.**’ (Narrated by Abu Dawood, 4/152)

Of course, it is seen that Islam values and acknowledges the sanctity and nobleness of the face and hence forbids it from being struck. If one strikes to obliterate/ destroy the face, surely it transgresses the moral code of the face being valued and hence considered a sin.

However, when it comes to say war or self-defence. Should this rule still stand? Of course, it is safe to assume that during self defense and war it's about life and death and one surely can't help but strike the face. What can we say of such a situation? If such a situation is approved as an exception to the ruling, then would it be forbidden to practise one's combat skills (for either self-defence or war) which includes punching the face? Given, for certain techniques to be applied in the streets and war, they need to be practised and pressure tested.

In addition, to my question of whether striking the face is legal under certain situations. Could we argue that striking the face is halal, **in combat sports training**, as long as we make sure we don't harm our partner (i.e. wearing protective headgear and trading light punches)?

I hope, someone out there can clarify my concerns regarding this topic.

Jazzakallahu Khair

Comment: I didn't read the full text of your post, but I'm pretty sure that there are posts that address this topic somehow. See for example [Is boxing haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9498/is-boxing-haram) and [Are sports like boxing and martial arts permissible in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/are-sports-like-boxing-and-martial-arts-permissible-in-islam)

Comment: To some extent...but I don't just ask about sports but also about self-defence and warfare.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a comprehensive list, but some possible exceptions include:

- In war against disbelievers. This has been claimed as an exception by a faction of the scholars in their commentaries on the hadith, like [here](https://shamela.ws/book/16584/2180#p1) and [here](https://shamela.ws/book/8176/5680#p1). This is taken from the fact that the [full wording](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2612a) of the hadith on prohibition of hitting the face is specific to a brother , i.e. a Muslim - because 'brother' is used in Islamic texts for a Muslim and not for a disbeliever.

  > إذا قاتل أحدكم **أخاه** فليجتنب الوجه
  >
  > When any one of you fights **with his brother** he should avoid striking at the face.
  >
  > <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2612a)</sup>

  And there is evidence that suggest that the ruling for disbelievers is different: Allah commands during battle with the disbelievers:

  > فاضربوا فوق الأعناق
  >
  > So strike them over the necks
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 8:12](https://quran.com/8:12?translations=203)</sup>

  > وقيل : للمؤمنين ... وقال محمد بن يزيد : ...  المعنى أنهم أبيح لهم ضرب الوجوه وما قرب منها
  >
  > And it has been said that it is a command to the believers. ... And Muhammad bin Yazid said: ... The meaning is that it is permissible to strike at the faces and what is near to it.
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura8-aya12.html)</sup>

  And also because we know that the angels strike the faces of the disbelievers at the time of death - this would not be the case if their faces had sanctity near Allah:

  > يضربون وجوههم وأدبارهم
  >
  > striking their faces and their backs
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 47:27](https://quran.com/47/27?translations=20) and  [Quran 8:50](https://quran.com/8/50?translations=20)</sup>

  There is also corroboration for this in ahadith. During the battle of Hunain, the Prophet ﷺ threw dirt into the faces of the enemy:

  > فلما غشوا رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم نزل عن البغلة ثم قبض قبضة من تراب من الأرض ثم استقبل به وجوههم فقال ‏"‏ شاهت الوجوه ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فما خلق الله منهم إنسانا إلا ملأ عينيه ترابا بتلك القبضة
  >
  > The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) got down from his mule, picked up a handful of dust from the ground, threw it into their (enemy) faces and said: "May these faces be deformed". There was no one among the enemy whose eyes were not filled with the dust from this handful.
  >
  > <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1777)</sup>

  And during the battle of Badr, Zubair ibn al-Awam killed a heavily armored foe by piercing his eye:

  > فحملت عليه بالعنزة، فطعنته في عينه فمات
  >
  > I attacked him with the spear and pierced his eye and he died.
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3998)</sup>
- In Qisas. According to some jurists (this is a minority view) retaliation takes place for a slap to the face even when it does not cause a visible injury.

  > وأقاد أبو بكر وابن الزبير وعلي وسويد بن مقرن من لطمة‏
  >
  > Abu Bakr, Ibn Az-Zubair, 'Ali and Suwaid bin Muqarrin gave the judgement of Al-Qisas (equality in punishment) in cases of slapping
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6896)</sup>

  While there is agreement that there is retaliation for a proper injury to the face.

  > والعين بالعين والأنف بالأنف والأذن بالأذن والسن بالسن والجروح قصاص
  >
  > An eye for an eye, a nose for a nose, an ear for an ear, a tooth for a tooth, and for wounds is legal retribution.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 5:45](http://quran.com/5/45)</sup>
- In dealing with an intruder. According to some madhabs it is permissible to strike at the face of an intruder who is peeping into one's house without permission.

  > لو أعلم أنك تنظر لطعنت به في عينك
  >
  > Had I known that you were looking I would have pierced your eye
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/15)</sup>

  > جاء ملك الموت إلى موسى عليه السلام . فقال له : أجب ربك قال فلطم موسى عليه السلام عين ملك الموت ففقأها
  >
  > The angel of death came (unannounced, in human form) to Moses عليه السلام  and said: “Answer the call of your Lord.” Moses عليه السلام (did not recognize him and) slapped the eye of the angel of death and put it out.
  >
  > <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2372b)</sup>

Comment: I am confused how the ruling against striking is only specific to Muslims cuz the hadith clearly said cuz Adam was made in his own image. Adam means all of humanity

Answer (score 0):

The hadith you quoted is itself about fighting, including where the intention is to kill, i.e. warfare, qitaal:

> وإذا قاتل أحدكم فليجتنب الوجه
>
> "fa idha qaatil a7adukum fa'lyajtanib al wajh"
>
> "when one of you fights, avoid the face"

Further explaining this, from islaqa.info:

> Al-Haafiz said: “This prohibition also includes all those who are struck for the purpose of hadd or ta’zeer punishments or discipline. According to the hadeeth narrated by Abu Bakrah and others, which was recorded by Abu Dawood and others, about the woman who had committed adultery, the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) commanded that she should be stoned to death, and said, ‘Stone her, but avoid the face.’ (Narrated by Abu Dawood, 4/152). If that is the command in the case of one who is being punished and is going to die anyway, then the rule is even more applicable in cases of lesser severity.” See al-Fath, 5/216

So, striking the face is not allowed; whether in warfare or applying the hudud, which are obligatory; never mind striking the face in sports practice.

Turning to warfare; where you say:

> Of course, it is safe to assume that during self defense and war it's about life and death and one surely can't help but strike the face. What can we say of such a situation? If such a situation is approved as an exception to the ruling, then would it be forbidden to practise one's combat skills (for either self-defence or war) which includes punching the face?

The rule about avoiding the face still applies. Bows and arrows, lances and the catapult (at Ta'if) were used at the time of the prophet saw without restricting them because they may have hit someone in the face; but this is not an exception, because what is aimed at isn't the face; if a rock thrown by a catapult hit someone in the face that doesn't contradict not aiming at the face, because aiming at the face or not is the choice of the one who aims; while where the blow lands is the fate of the one aimed at. So as long as the arrow or lance or catapult isn't aimed at the face then it's allowed and there is no exception to the rule, so your assumption isn't correct and the argument:

> such a situation is approved as an exception to the ruling

isn't correct I'm afraid.

About the second part of your question:

> Could we argue that striking the face is halal, in combat sports training, as long as we make sure we don't harm our partner (i.e. wearing protective headgear and trading light punches)?

As mentioned in the comment from @Medi1Saif, there are other posts here on this, and it seems boxing as a sport is unanimously and emphatically not allowed: see [this post](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/10427/ruling-on-boxing) and [this post](https://www.thedeenshow.com/the-rulings-pertinent-to-boxing-martial-arts/).

In the last article, it is mentioned that the practice may be modified to not include hitting the face, which is actually what some clubs do; some street fighting and martial arts clubs run by muslims don't let people aim at the face or use shadow boxing or maintaining a distance; for proper boxing as a sport, even training for it, if sparring with a partner you are not allowed to hit the face regardless of whether a face protector is used or not. I have known brothers and family members who gave up boxing because of this, and they switched to other martial arts; equally there are clubs where they don't practice any actual hitting of the face, people do it for fitness (and the fact that body blows in street fighting are just as effective if not more so). But if you want to say, is it ever under any circumstances allowed to strike the face, then no, I never came accross anyone who ever said it was halal.

Comment: Striking the face of a disbeliever in war is considered an exception by some.

Comment: yeah, jazak Allah, the only reference I can find for an exception is what people say Mulla ‘Ali Qaari said in Mirqaat Al-Mafaateeh; where he (effectively) says it's allowed if there's no option and one's own life is in danger, in which case the hukm of darurah, life or death neccessity supercedes it, rather than there being an exception to the rule - as I understand it, at least.

Comment: @secretsquirrel Thanks for the answer. I now understand the weight of the situation as I see that striking the face whether in warfare or even in self-defence, regardless is haram.  However, as a response to UmH, you seem to say that when it comes to life and death, hitting the face would only be allowed as an act of necessity, which is probably the only exception. Now I would just like to add a couple of follow up questions if you don't mind answering....

Comment: 1) Essentially you are saying, even using headgear or full-face covering, striking the face would be haram. But as we know using face covering, may protect against ure face being obliterated and the whole ruling behind why striking the face is not allowed is becuz Islamically the face is considered Nobel. But given u're using a face covering or a headgear, u're punched are barely or not even touching the face in the first place. So why should that be a problem?

Comment: 2) Since the ruling involves not puching the face, can we at least practise, our punches/kicks to head, ie to the temple or the area around the ears in other words the side of the head?

Comment: 3) As a martial arts enthusiast, I understand the importance of defending agianst head hits, especially in self-defence or on the streets. Since getting punched or knocked out by a kick or punch to the face is thousand times worser than getting punched in the body. Do you think it would be okay to at least practise by getting used to getting punched in the head and learn proper defence against it? I mean, u're not striking the face but say your coach or your training partner who happens to be a non-muslim can help me with that?

Comment: OK, insha Allah I'm going to ask brothers I know who run clubs and train and ill get back to you.

Comment: @secretsquirrel Did u get the chance your friends who run martial clubs?

Comment: @EPIC Tube HD yeah and so what they do is aim for the top or side of the head, with jabs and hooks, they practice uppercuts but are told not to land them or make contact in sparring. That's boxing, I found out about krav, at a place run by a brother, they just say don't aim for the face but they teach things like eye jab techniques, which seems a bit pointless - why are you teaching it, in a fight you wouldn't be able to do that unless absolutely necessary; but they stress that too apparently. In short you can get around it but is it still dodgy ? -- more

Comment: cont -- I would advise, check out surah al talaq (65th surah) ayahs 2:3 before considering this topic: "And whosoever has Taqwa of Allah, He will make a way for him to get out. 3. And He will provide him from where he never could imagine." -- so brother, teach your own martial arts technique which takes heed of what the prophet saw said and may Allah reward you and enable you to benefit others by it.

Comment: @secretsquirrel thanks for getting back...I'd like to say, well that I'm kinda sceptical about not being able to strike the face when say it comes to war and self-defence and since there's no direct evidence from our prophet's saying not to strike the face in war or self-defence, I shy from saying it is haram. Since in the end, we can conclude that war and self-defence boils doing to life and death and hence do whatever is necessary to stay alive or protect life. When our prophet talked about for those who fight or when he said if u're in an altercation with your brother avoid the face...

Comment: ....I think he meant for those who causally fight...or in an "ALTERCATION" but...war and self-defence isn't an altercation. Also, u didn't seem to comment about the whether punches to the head would be okay when say ure wearing headgear or face covering. Cuz look u aren't exactly punching the face when ure wearing protection, u're punching the headgear itself, RIGHT? Furthermore, headgear protect the sanctity of the face, so it should be alright! Also, what's ure comment on getting punched in the face to defend against it rather than u throwing the punch herself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110759/discussion-between-epic-tube-hd-and-secret-squirrel).