# Islamic view on exercise

Tags: hadith, health

Is there any Hadith that discusses the importance of exercise, its benefits and what kind of exercise is considered good, etc.?

Comment: [**This answer**](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/213/59) at [**"Islam and adventure sports"**](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/204/59) might also answer your question.

Comment: Please do some research before posting a question in the future. Your question as is lacks even the basic kind of research. Thank you.

Comment: @Noah its a question to which i seek an answer. thats what stackexchange is about. all questions need not be as easy to research and even if they are, the person asking the question might not have acess to research material. Please review your comment and take this to meta if you still have issues

Comment: @Noah: Noah, I don't mean offense, rather: I seek to understand you. You seem to be telling a lot of people that their question lacks research. Could you explain to us what you mean by that? After all, people come here to seek knowledge (which, in my opinion, is a synonym of research). In your opinion, should this be a site only for discussion among experts?

Answer (score 5):

> And the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) said: “The strong believer is better and more beloved to Allaah
>   than the weak believer.” Narrated by Muslim, 6774.

According to the fatwa [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/40527), muslims should be strong physically and mentally.

Personally, I think those exercises which just make your biceps big are stupid exercises, you need exercises which will give you overall body strength, core stability, flexibility, agility, and stamina.

I used to work with someone who was a professional bodybuilder, and he said when it's competition time, his water intake has to be so precise to give him the perfect definition that he kept getting full body cramps due to the lack of water.

What use is such a body if you can't move properly?  So personally, I would recommend staying away from that type of thing, and finding an exercise which will give you strength, core stability, flexibility, agility, and stamina.

The only exercises I can think of which does all these together are the gymnastic exercises.  Please note, I am not suggesting you become a professional gymnast.  What I am saying is that gymnasts do certain exercises which give them amazing strength, core stability, flexibility, agility, and stamina all at the same time!  What I am suggesting is that you find out what they do and do that.  Plus find a decent martial arts system not concerned about competitions and belts.

Just keep these words in mind, fundamentals and conditioning.